# Can I make a phone call from HTML on Android?

Tags: android, html, phone-call

To make a phone call via HTML on an iPhone I create an `<A/>` tag with an href formatted as: `<a href='tel:123-555-1212'>Dial Me</a>`.

Is there an equivelant for HTML on Android?

CLARIFICATION - using the format href='tele:123-555-1212' does indeed work on on android.  I was testing the app within a native Java wrapper on the device.  It does not appear as if we can make a call from a web application hosted in a Native Wrapper.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Yes you can; it works on [Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/it/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) too:

> tel: phone_number
> Calls the entered
> phone number. Valid telephone numbers
> as defined in the IETF RFC 3966 are
> accepted. Valid examples include the
> following:
>
> ```
> * tel:2125551212
> * tel: (212) 555 1212
> ```

The Android browser uses the Phone app to handle the “tel” scheme, as defined by RFC 3966.
Clicking a link like:

```
<a href="tel:2125551212">2125551212</a>
```

on Android will bring up the Phone app and pre-enter the digits for 2125551212 without autodialing.

Have a look to [RFC3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966)

Comment: when you click the link the iphone inits the call automatically (autodial)? or it is like Android? (open the dialer, and you need to press the call button).

Comment: Make sure you have this: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> in your Manifest.xml

Answer (score 25):

I have just written an app which can make a call from a web page - I don't know if this is any use to you, but I include anyway:

in your onCreate you'll need to use a webview and assign a WebViewClient, as below:

```
browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit);
browser.setWebViewClient(new InternalWebViewClient());
```

then handle the click on a phone number like this:

```
private class InternalWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         if (url.indexOf("tel:") > -1) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more pointers.

Comment: Thanks - yeah that's a good approach!

I ended up adding access to my app from JavaScript w/ addJavascriptInterface

Answer (score 22):

Generally on Android, if you simply display the phone number, and the user taps on it, it will pull it up in the dialer.  So, you could simply do

```html
For more information, call us at <b>416-555-1234</b>
```

When the user taps on the bold part, since it's formatted like a phone number, the dialer will pop up, and show `4165551234` in the phone number field. The user then just has to hit the call button.

You might be able to do

```html
For more information, call us at <a href='tel:416-555-1234'>416-555-1234</a>
```

to cover both devices, but I'm not sure how well this would work. I'll give it a try shortly and let you know.

EDIT:
I just gave this a try on my HTC Magic running a rooted Rogers 1.5 with SenseUI:

```html
For more information, call us at <a href='tel:416-555-1234'>416-555-1234</a><br />
<br />
Call at <a href='tel:416-555-1234'>our number</a>
<br />
<br />
<a href='416-555-1234'>Blah</a>
<br />
<br />
For more info, call <b>416-555-1234</b>
```

The first one, surrounding with the link and printing the phone number, worked perfectly. Pulled up the dialer with the hyphens and all.  The second, saying `our number` with the link, worked exactly the same. This means that using `<a href='tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx'>` should work across the board, but I wouldn't suggest taking my one test as conclusive.

Linking straight to the number did the expected: Tried to pull up the nonexistent file from the server.

The last one did as I mentioned above, and pulled up the dialer, but without the nice formatting hyphens.