# How to force numbers to be dialable on mobile devices

Tags: html, mobile

Modern smartphones detect phone number formats and automatically turn them into links that upon clicking will insert the number in your dial pad so you can dial.

For example:

(310) 555 - 5555 or 
310.555.5543

Is there a way to force a number that doesn't follow standard phone number formats to also become dialable?

for example: 3949392.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774243/can-i-make-a-phone-call-from-html-on-android). Use the `tel:` prefix in the `<a href>` tag.

```
<a href="tel:2125551212">212-555-1212</a>
```

As for the non-standard phone numbers, just strip out all non-numerical characters like this:

```
<a href="tel:39493922">Call 3949392.2</a>
```