# HTML telephone link for phones format

Tags: html

I am making an html link for a phone.

This is what I have:

```
<a href="tel:1-888-888-8888"> 1-888-888-8888</a>
```

Will phones recognize this, or do I need to change it to:

```
<a href="tel:18888888888"> 1-888-888-8888</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774243/can-i-make-a-phone-call-from-html-on-android

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Visual separators (except for spaces) are allowed in the uri.

From [RFC 3966 "The tel URI for Telephone Numbers"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966):

> 5.1.1. **Separators in Phone Numbers**

> Phone numbers MAY contain visual separators.  Visual separators
> ('visual-separator') merely aid readability and are not used for URI
> comparison or placing a call ... "tel" URIs MUST NOT use spaces in visual separators ...

Comment: However, spaces are not allowed... from the above link: "tel" URIs MUST NOT use spaces in visual separators to avoid excessive escaping.