# How can I make a link from a website to make a call using android?

Tags: android, html

How can I make a link from a website to make a call using android?

There is any problem if my website is not a mobile site? My website is in godaddy.
when I tested my app I used  a mexican number phone. So what I`m doing wrong? 
Can someone help me to solve my problem?

I  was using

```
<A href "tel:+xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx">
```

and

```
<A href "tel:xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML telephone link for phones format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242590/html-telephone-link-for-phones-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an `=`, and you have to include some text:

```
<a href="tel:+xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx">+xx-xxx-xxx-xxxx</a>
```