# Hyperlink for telephone number and redirect

Tags: android, html, iphone, web, window.open

We are building an application where the initial access would be from a mobile phone.  As such upon entry to the page. we want to give the user the opportunity to dial in if necessary, and as that occurs open another page in the browser in the same window.

I have tried this:

```
<a href="thispage.htm" target="_self" onclick="window.open('tel://1-555-555-5555'">Dial</a>
```

as well as this:

```
<a href="tel://1-555-555-5555" onclick="window.open('thispage.htm','_self';">Dial</a>
```

Neither approach has worked. In the first instance, the hyperlink works but the telephone dialer doesn't recognize the onClick event, and the opposite occurs when the second approach is attempted, i.e. the telephone dialer shows the number but the page doesn't open in the browser.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!
Mike

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I make a phone call from HTML on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774243/can-i-make-a-phone-call-from-html-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<a href="tel:2125551212">2125551212</a>
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774243/can-i-make-a-phone-call-from-html-on-android).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I wasn't clear... In the above code, the hyperlink portion of the code works fine.

What isn't working is the window.open code! My guess is that the solution will be more like my second piece of code posted above, as when the "tel://555-555-5555" is used as the hyperlink it appears as expected in the dialer on a mobile phone, but if I return to the browser from the dialer the browser is not pointing to the page referenced in the window.open event.

Mike