# href="tel:" on android is trying to add contact instead of triggering a call

Tags: android, cordova, href

I have a standard html tag:

```
<a href="tel:08435034853"...
```

While IOS and some android devices are triggering call, others like nexus7/android4.4 are displaying popup with action buttons: Close / Add to contacts

Couldn't actually find anything about it, is it how new android works?

Does anyone know is it possible to force a call on all android devices?

Comment: If multiple apps register to handle the "tel" content URI, then Android will prompt the user which app/action they want to use to handle the "tel" link. There is no way around this.

Comment: try to achieve it via a plugin https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin using not the `href` but the `on-click`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774243/can-i-make-a-phone-call-from-html-on-android) thread too on this topic. It has some potential tips which might work on some exceptional devices.

Furthermore: not all Android devices are capable of voice calling. E.g. I'm pretty sure that the Nexus 7 that you're mentioning is not. In such cases it's a sensible alternative to offer the user to add the number to the contacts instead. Isn't it possible that your problematic devices simply lack the voice calling feature?

Comment: I don't see a difference. Are you suggesting not having the phone number as the text of the anchor?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea, it's worth a try. And as a sidenote: you mentioned that one of the problematic devices was a Nexus 7. Are you sure that that device supports voice calling at all? I might have missed something but I'm pretty sure it does not, so a sensible action would be to add that number to the contacts instead.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy running Android 4.4. You make a good point though, this tablet doesn't support voice calls, so it makes sense that it doesn't have an option to call. Maybe make a new answer and I'll give you the bounty. I can't give it for this answer.

Comment: Edited this answer instead to reduce clutter.

Answer (score -1):

Create one javascript function and add the following code:

```
function makeCall(contactNo) {
    document.location.href = 'tel:' + contactNo;
}
```

And this is working fine in android 4.4