# I don't want a default android browser pop up that asks if the user wants to call the number when the user clicks to make a call

Tags: javascript, android, browser, click, phone-call

How do I do that? Required: when I click on the number, it must make a call  automatically(redirect to dialer).

Comment: I don't **know**, but I *bet* you can't.

Comment: Yeah, it would be stupidly abusable if you could

Answer (score 0):

As you are talking about the default android browser I assume you have a site that you want to allow the user to contact you from.

```
<a href="tel:2125551212">2125551212</a>
```

A click on the number will open the dialer (but you still need to press the dial button).

Possible duplicate of: [Can I make a phone call from HTML on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774243/can-i-make-a-phone-call-from-html-on-android)

Comment: I just want to open dialer on click, but on samsung phone's native browser, a layer with options 1. call, 2. send sms, 3. save to contacts, comes, then i have to press again on call. then dialer comes, i just want to skip middle prompt.

Comment: strange, it does not happen on my LG G3 with android lollipop

Comment: it happens on some specific models. even on my canvas it does not happen.