# Phone link in HTML for iOS and Android

Tags: android, html, ios, phone-call

on my website I want to integrate a call-by-click phone number. When you click on the phone number (or a button like "Call me now!") a call should start.

How can I do this in HTML? It must work for iOS and Android. I need one code for iOS an Android browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774243/can-i-make-a-phone-call-from-html-on-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to implement this into an app, this:

in android, you can do this to detect PhoneLinks:

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.contains("tel:")) {
                    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
           }
    });
```

in IOS, you can enable this on UIwebView's properties, inside Detection, there is the "Phone Numbers" tick. it will detect any phone number or phoneLink.

this is the code on your website, it will automatically trigger the phone:

```
<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
```

more info on phoneLinks (works on both systems):

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: I took this for my website: <a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>
In iOS Safari it works fine, but in the webview in my app it does‘t work. Why that? Any ideas?

Comment: in the webview, use the code i provided. you have to create a custom webview and override the ShouldOverrideUrlLoading method so it detects "tel:"

Comment: The problem is my HTML code. By using this <a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a> in my app it works fine. My my html code is: <map name="Text161Kopie459HotArea">
<area shape="rect" coords="15,10,804,66" href="http://www.empl.com">
</map> 
I changed it to: <map name="Text161Kopie459HotArea">
<area shape="rect" coords="15,10,804,66" href="tel:1-408-555-5555">
</map>
 but it doesn‘t work. Why that?

Comment: please post the complete html code in your question by editing it.

Comment: It works now in my iOS app. <div id="box28">
        <a href="tel:03303-500872"><img src="bild/Text161_Kopie459.png">
    </div> 
In my Android app I'll test later.

Comment: you should close the <a> tag after the img tag. ex: <a href="tel:03303-500872"><img src="bild/Text161_Kopie459.png"</a> android is very strict on parsing documents.

Comment: Okay, just did it: <div id="box28">
        <a href="tel:03303-500872"><img src="bild/Text161_Kopie459.png"></a>
    </div> 
It works fine on Android, too.

Comment: let me know if it works in android, and if it does so, please accept my answer.  glad to be of help.

Comment: It seems to work on Android, too. Thanks for help. I just accepted your answer.