# Launch dialer app from meteor app

Tags: android, meteor, android-dialer, meteor-cordova

I have been trying hard to figure out a way to launch dialer app to make phone call from an app developed on meteor platform but did not find a way to do so.

In meteor [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/App-accessRule) they have mentioned meteor launches dialer app if its wrapped in `<a>` tag eg: `<a href="tel:+1 xxx xxx xxxx> +1 xxx xxx xxxx </a>`. This approach works when I am deploying meteor app on server and opening it through mobile web browser. But if I run it on my android device using command `meteor run android-device` it does not work. When i click the link nothing happens. Please suggest me a way to make it work as android app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the comments in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2774342/2104665)?

Comment: I have just started coding on meteor platform and havent encountered  Manifest.xml by now. I may be missing it, but answer by @Michel solved my issue.
Thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: I meant the comment "This does not work in Android API 19 or prior". I don't know if it's true or not, but if it is, it might be a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to notice... I am targeting  API 19 + for my prototype so it wont be an issue as of now, but going forward, I will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look on cordova-plugin like call-number : [CordovaCallNumberPlugin](https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin)
I have install it in my meteor cordova project. It works fine on Android and iOS.

```js
callSuccess = function(){
  console.log('call done');
  }

callError = function(){
  console.log('Error : verify phone number');
  }

window.plugins.CallNumber.callNumber(callSuccess, callError,'+1123456789',true);
```